# Easiest way to download a file in Lua

Tags: lua

My Lua application make a http:request, get a response in the JSON format, decode that JSON to a table. OK.

Now, I am able to extract an url that was inside that JSON file.

But, how can I save a image url to a file in Lua? Are there libraries available?

Edit:

How I take the JSON file inside Lua:

```
json_lib = require('json')

local http = libs.net.http();

    local resp = http:request({
        method = "get", 
        url = "http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/images?api_key=MY_API_KEY_HERE&name=zedd&format=json&results=1&start=0&license=unknown",
    }); 


    local json_full = resp.content;     

    local str_decoded = json_lib.decode(json_full)

    function RecursiveSearch(aTable)

        for key, value in pairs(aTable) do --unordered search
            if(type(value) == "table") then
                print(key,value)
                RecursiveSearch(value)
            else
                --Do something with this.
                print(key,value)
            end
        end
    end
    RecursiveSearch(str_decoded)
```

My JSON response is:

```
{
                   "response":{
                      "status":{
                         "version":"4.2",
                         "code":0,
                         "message":"Success"
                      },
                      "start":0,
                      "total":20,
                      "images":[
                         {
                            "url":"http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/_/67419844/ZEDD.png",
                            "license":{
                               "type":"unknown",
                               "attribution":"n/a",
                               "url":"http://www.last.fm/music/ZEDD/+images"
                            }
                         }
                      ]
                   }
                }
```

So I want to save on disk the first URL with the picture of the artist.

Comment: Are you talking about saving the actual image itself or just the url text link to it?

Comment: I want to save the image itself. The url text I already accomplished. Thanks for the interest.

Comment: You must already be using a library to fetch the json document, no? Wouldn't just using that to download the image file work?

Comment: @EtanReisner, I am using [JSON4Lua](http://json.luaforge.net/). I did not see anything about file download.

Comment: You are using that to parse the JSON document. How are you getting the JSON document that you parse in the first place? Are you manually (outside of lua) making the http request to fetch the file?

Comment: @EtanReisner I am making a http:request to [Echonest](http://developer.echonest.com) inside Lua. I make something like this:

[code](http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/images?api_key=2ZWMQ2OM3D4OKYRND&id=ARH6W4X1187B99274F&format=json&results=1&start=0&license=unknown)

Comment: Ok. So how are you making that request from lua?

Comment: @EtanReisner Edited the info on the question.

Comment: So as I indicated you already have a library capable of making the request for the image you want. Just use it and instead of treating the response body as json treat it as the binary data of the image you wanted and write it to a file.

Comment: @EtanReisner, I did not understand this part: treat it as the binary data of the image

Do you have some Code Snippets?

Comment: That's the response you get for your initial request. Your second request is going to be to that image URL. As such your response will not be a JSON document but the image you wanted to fetch. So the response body will not be json but will be the image binary data. Just write it out to a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add something like (untested):

```
local imageresp = http:request({
    method = "get", 
    url = url_from_decoded_json,
});

local imagefile = io.open("some_file", "w")
imagefile:write(resp.content)
imagefile:close()
```

to the end of your script.

Comment: Thanks Etan Reisner for the last answer. Sorry for the delay on my return.

The problem was that the windows program that I was using had a bad binary data handling. It was saving just 1kb (corrupted) image file.

I reported the bug and the devs updated the beta program and the problem was solved. Now I can download the image with your above idea.

bye